# Is VB 6 worth learning today?

Tags: vb6

How necessary is it to learn VB6 and what are the advantages of using this language today? Does it really have advantages?

Comment: bit too subjective with no right answer, and any answer being time sensitive.

Comment: perhaps this question should be on the programming stack

Comment: The place I work at still has applications written in VB6, which I support. The same question could be asked about COBOL or RPG, many will say 'no' and many will say 'yes'. But if you look at the facts, most companies have a lot of VB6 applications which they hope to port to .NET -- but it is a large challenge. Many VB6 applications will stay in existence for a long time (like COBOL or RPG -- there are many things .NET can't do yet), but I don't think you'll see much new development with the technology. Career wise, I would shy away from it and try to move towards the new technologies.

Comment: I suggest you try this question on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this point, nobody should be using VB6 for new development work, however, there is a lot of existing VB6 code that needs to be maintained and/or ported.  Much of the existing VB6 code will be internal line-of-business applications, so the question of whether to learn it or not would depend on your employeers needs.